# COLLADA scene shows different rotation axis when imported in ScenKit

Tags: scene, collada

I have a blender scene with a mushroom inside it, which seems to be perfectly straight aligned with the axes:

[image]

When I import it in xcode (inside a scnassets directory), although I select "always use the Y-up axis", the object seems to be rotated and placed in a wrong direction:

[image]

It seems like if SceneKit is using a different coordinate system. But unlike for obj files, there's no way to fix that when I export the files. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you just have to make allowances in your workflow. The images in your question seem to suggest to me that the issue is that the axis Blender labels as "X" is being named by your target environment "Y"; so when you're making your object, mentally swap the x and y axes as you build your model.